# jQuery - Form validation is one event late

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using the GoogleMapsAPI to help users to fill my form faster.

The form is optional so the submit button is enabled by default, whenever an user choose any address using the API autocomplete I'd like to check if `postal_code` and `locality` inputs are filled, in case it isn't the button should be disabled.

The problem is that the jQuery code is one event late, it gets called before `postal_code` and `locality` are updated.

The button should be enabled when the user has selected an option and both fields are filled.

See demo on https://jsfiddle.net/osvktsxz/

**HTML:**

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text">
<input id="postal_code" placeholder="prefill postal code">
<input id="locality" placeholder="prefill locality">
<br>
<button type="button" disabled>Submit</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click keyup change input blur', '#autocomplete', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0){
      $('button').prop('disabled', true);
      if ($('#postal_code').val().length > 1 && $('#locality').val().length > 1) {
          $('button').prop('disabled', false);
      }
  } else {
      $('button').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});

// See fiddle for Google Maps API.
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Use a callback from the autocomplete. It is async

Comment: please don't ask us to debug minified code. there's a tidy button on jsfiddle you can use to make it readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should use the callback. The `place_changed` event is always going to be the last one to fire, so you should do whatever validation you need to in there (I did none in my answer, you can write the validation code yourself) and use that to enable the button. You only need the `keyup` to ensure the button is disabled when the user begin to type a new address. If you add `onclick` and `blur` you're going to have problems when a user clicks into the input and doesn't change it.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#autocomplete', function() {
   $('button').prop('disabled', false);
});

function formIsValid(){
    // you write this code
    return true;
}

function initialize() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("autocomplete"), {
    types: ["geocode"]
  }), google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
    fillInAddress()
    if(formIsValid()) $('button').prop('disabled', false);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, I used the google maps eventListener to call my function.

**Javascript:**

```
function updateForm() {
    if ($('#postal_code').val().length > 1 && $('#locality').val().length > 1) {
        $('#submit-form').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#submit-form').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
    updateForm();
});
```

`updateForm()` will be called after `fillInAddress()`